# after using windows in dual boot I can't see any file or folder in the disk when using ubuntu

Tags: disk-usage, hidden-files

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS in dual boot with wondows 10. Today I opened windows for the first time and after closing window and starting ubuntu I couldn't see any file or folder in the disk.

show hidden files are also check but still there is no file.
here you can see in the pic. 
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENtj0.png)

Comment: Files are there if you login in Windows?

Comment: No I couldn't see in windows too

Comment: Turn off fast start up in Windows. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions and More explanation of NTFS driver & Windows hibernation
http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation